# Overloading operator<< for enum class inside template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't seem to be able to overload `operator<<` for an enum class inside a template class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    enum class E { A, B };

    E e;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const typename S<T>::E e)
{
    return s << static_cast<int>(e);
}

int main()
{
    const S<int> s {};
    std::cerr << s.e;    // error
}
```

The exact error message produced by Visual Studio 2015 is:

```
error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const S<int>::E' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Both gcc and clang fail with a similar error message.

Two notes:

- If I change the enum class to a plain enum, the code compiles fine.
- If I specialize the `operator<<` overload for `T = int`, the code compiles fine as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator template cannot deduce `T` because of its use prior to `::` (consider what specializing `S` might do to the type `S::E`).  When using an unscoped enumeration, you’re getting one of the standard overloads via an implicit conversion to an integer.

The usual approach here is to define the operator as a (non-template) friend.  Then overload resolution, rather than template argument deduction, is responsible for selecting among them.

Comment: Thanks! So If I can't modify `S`, I'm left with defining `operator<<` for full specializations of `S` then?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: Yes, unfortunately: there just isn’t a way to use the template system to find `T`.